# Pass Enter Key in Batch File

Tags: file, batch-file

I have used start /wait to run the exe. After exe is complete it asks for Press any key to continue. How is it possible to pass Enter Key through same batch file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the application in question and how it processes input. In most cases you should be able to just pipe input to the program:

```
echo.|some.exe
```

If they are reading from standard input, they will read a line break in this case. E.g. `echo.|pause` prints `Press any key to continue . . .` and exits immediately.

Within `start /wait` you likely need to wrap it into another `cmd` call:

```
start /wait cmd /c "echo.|some.exe"
```

Comment: I tried adding it after start /wait executable, but it didn't work. Should I do something differently?